# Does R store the values of recursive functions that it has obtained?

Tags: r, recursion

I have used Mathematica for many years and have just started using R for programming.
In both programs we can define recursive functions. In Mathematica there is a way to save values of functions. I am not sure if this is the default setting for R. Take the Fibonacci numbers for example. In Mathematica

```js
fibonacci[0]=1;
fibonacci[1]=1;
fibonacci[n_]:=fibonacci[n-1]+fibonacci[n-2];
```

Let's say to find fibonacci[10]. It needs to find all fibonacci[i] from i=2, ..., 9 first.
After that, if we want to find fibonacci[11], then the program needs to go through the whole process to find all fibonacci[i] from i=2, ..., 10 again. It does not store the values it has obtained. A modification in Mathematica is

```js
fibonacci[0]=1;
fibonacci[1]=1;
fibonacci[n_]:=fibonacci[n]=fibonacci[n-1]+fibonacci[n-2];
```

In this way, once we have computed the value fibonacci[10], it is stored, and we do not need to compute it again to find fibonacci[11]. This can save a lot of time to find, say fibonacci[10^9].

The Fibonacci function in R can be defined similarly:

```
fibonacci = function(n) { 
    if (n==0 | n==1) { n } 
    else {fibonacci[n-1]+fibonacci[n-2]}}
```

Does R store the value fibonacci[10] after we compute it? Does R compute fibonacci[10] again when we want to find fibonacci[11] next?  Similar questions have been asked for other programmings.

Edit: as John has suggested, I have computed fibonacci[30] (which is 832040) and then fibonacci[31] (which is 1346269). It took longer to get fibonacci[31]. So it appears that the R function defined above does not store the values. How to change the program so that it can store the intermediate values of a recursive function?

Comment: Is `fibonacci(60)` fast in R? That should answer your question. The actual code you posted was for a factorial. That was doubtless a typo.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for pointing that out. I changed my function halfway through writing question. I will correct it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R does not do this by default, and similarly as you see Mathematica doesn't either. You can implement memoise yourself or use the `memoise` package.

```
fib <- function(i){
  if(i == 0 || i == 1)
    i
  else
    fib(i - 1) + fib(i - 2)
}
system.time(fib(30))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.92    0.00    1.84 
library(memoise)
fib <- memoise(fib) # <== Memoise magic
system.time(fib(100)) 
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.02    0.00    0.03
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, which is essentially the same as using memoise: generate and store the first k Fibonacci numbers in a sequence, and then print the last one from that sequence as the k-th Fibonacci number:

```
fibSeq = function(k) {
    fsequence = c(0, 1)
    for (i in 1:k)
      fsequence = append(fsequence, fsequence[i]+fsequence[i-1])
    return(fsequence)
} # generate and store the first k Fibonacci numbers, k>=1

fibNum = function(k) {
  return(tail(fibSeq(k), n=1))
} # output the k-th Fibonacci number
```